# How can I get the original type of data after being processed by Object as Hash in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, hash

LeetCode 136 Single Number
Given an array of integers, every element appears twice except for one. Find that single one.

I have solved this problem by using Object-property in JS as Hash.
However, the property only allows string type, so all the data are automatically converted to string.

```
var singleNumber = function(nums) {
var hash = {}
for(var i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    if (hash.hasOwnProperty(nums[i]))
        delete hash[nums[i]]
    else
        hash[nums[i]] = 1
for(var x in hash)
    return Number(x) }
```

How can I get the original type of data after processing? In this problem I use Number() to convert.

However, if the array in this problem not only contains the number, but also the string. ['123',123,...] may fail with the solution above.

Comment: What kind of numbers are they? do you have floats as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be easily done, just store object instead of 1

https://jsfiddle.net/uo8v55qf/1/

```
var singleNumber = function(nums) {
var hash = {}
for(var i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    if (hash.hasOwnProperty(nums[i]))
        delete hash[nums[i]]
    else
        hash[nums[i]] = { value:nums[i], type: typeof nums[i]};
for(var x in hash)
 return hash[x];
}    
result = singleNumber(['123',123,'23']);
console.log(result);
console.log(result.value + ' type:' + result.type); //23 type:string

result = singleNumber(['123',123,23]);
console.log(result.value + ' type:' + result.type); //23 type:number
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution only works for integers. (or strings that can be parsed to integers)

```
var array = ['12', 12, 4, 33, 9, '33', 9]; // 4 is the element you search for

var hash = {};
array.forEach(function(number) {
    number = parseInt(number);
    // if the number doesn't exists initialize the hash entry with 1 otherwise add 1
    hash[number] = hash[number] ? 1 : ++hash[number]; 
});

for (var key in hash) {
    if (hash[key] === 1) console.log('Element ' + key + ' appears once');
}
```